# program unable to write in output file (StreamWrite issue)

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm a student and I made a program where I would read data from one file (`dimension.txt`), make a calculation out of it, then write the output on another file (`result.txt`). The program can read `dimension.txt`, but couldn't write in the output file `result.txt`. Thanks to anyone who can help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace AreaofRectangle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path + "/dimensions.txt");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + "//result.txt");
            Console.WriteLine("Content of the File");
            sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string str = sr.ReadLine();
            int rectangleCount = 1;
            while (str != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nRectangle " + rectangleCount);
                string[] number = str.Split(',');
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                string[] s = str.Split(',');

                int length = Int32.Parse(number[0]);
                int width = Int32.Parse(number[1]);
                int area = length * width;
                Console.WriteLine("Length: " + length);
                Console.WriteLine("Width: " + width);
                Console.WriteLine("Area: " + area);
                str = sr.ReadLine();
                rectangleCount++;
                sw.WriteLine("Length:" + length + " Width:" + width + " Area: " + " " + area);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What _specifically_ doesn't work? An exception is thrown? The machine catches fire?

Comment: What is the _exact_ value of `path`? **Do not guess**.

Comment: The program doesn't write to the output file result.txt, even though I initialized it and used WriteLine in the end.

the exact value of path is C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\bin\Debug.

Comment: Are there any exceptions shown? Does it work if you comment out `Console.ReadKey();`?

Comment: Why are you using `//` in the path?

Comment: Everything works fine - no errors or anything. It just doesn't write in the result.txt text document. I used // in the path because it was used by our mentor in programming.